# VSCode extension SCM view pane icons

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am maintaining a vscode scm extention. Everything works as expected. But there is one thing left. I want to have such quick action icons as shown in the screenshot below from the build in git scm. In the API documentation I didn't find anything about that.

[image: GIT: modified file]

Does anyone know how to get this to work? Or where I can find a sample code?

Thanks!

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/tree-view#view-actions

Answer (score 0):

With the provided link I was able to get icons in the file list.
In the package.json I duplicated an entry in the node `contributes > menues > scm > resourceState > context`

```
{
  "command": "extension.myCommand1",
  "when": "scmProvider == myProvider",
  "group": "inline"
}
```

The important information is the `group` property which has to be `inline`.
Beside that, to make this command visible you need to configure an icon.

In `contributes > commands` you can configure the command

```
{
  "command": "extension.myCommand1",
  "title": "Do something",
  "category": "myCat",
  "icon": {
    "dark": "myIcon.png",
    "light": "myIcon.png"
  }
}
```